# How do I test that an enum action method validates the object before creation or saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am trying to test that `Lead.new(params).active!` raises an error. What is the best way to go about this?

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { stale: 0, active: 1, converted: 2 }

  validate  :existing_lead, on: :create

  private

  def existing_lead
    if new_record? && (stale? || converted?)
      errors.add(:status, "invalid for new leads") 
    end
  end
end
```

I know I can set the enum value manually and then test `valid?` on the object that I instantiate, but I was hoping there was a way to test `stale!` and `converted!` which save to the database when called.

Comment: I think you mean that you want to test that `Lead.new.stale!` or `Lead.new.converted!` raise an error, since those are the ones that are invalid for new Leads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you're asking this way:

```
expect { Lead.new.stale! }.to raise_error(
  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, "Validation failed: Value invalid for new leads")
```